# Merge second columns in different xts objects contained in a list

Tags: r, list, apply, xts

I am new to R programming and I was trying to work with financial data. Currently I have built multiple xts objects which contain Close, High, Open and Low prices on a daily basis, and I have stored the multiple xts objects in a list (called Data) so that I can access them easily.

Now I want to create a larger xts object which contain only the "Close" prices for all the xts objects (which may have different dates in which case an NA will be the output) in the list

I have tried using apply functions but of no avail.

```
sapply(Data,function(x) merge(x,"[[", [,"CLOSE"]))
```

The code does not compile and throws an error, but i thought it should work something like this. Will really appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` within `Reduce`:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2018);
dates <- seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 5);
Data <- lapply(1:5, function(x)
    xts(x = data.frame(Close = rnorm(5), High = rnorm(5)), order.by = dates))

# Merge
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), lapply(Data, function(x) x[, "Close"]));
#                 Close    Close.1    Close.2    Close.3    Close.4
#2018-01-01 -0.42298398 -0.6430347  1.2638637 -0.2284119 -0.3594423
#2018-01-02 -1.54987816 -1.0300287  0.2501979  1.1786797 -1.2995363
#2018-01-03 -0.06442932  0.7124813  0.2581954 -0.2662727 -0.8698701
#2018-01-04  0.27088135 -0.4457721  1.7855342  0.5281408  1.0543623
#2018-01-05  1.73528367  0.2489796 -1.2197058 -1.7686592 -0.1486396
```

Comment: @RK01 If this answers your question please close the question by setting the check mark next to the solution.